# How can I test specific field of entity by JUnit if using validator?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, junit, bean-validation

I have some entity which stored in db.

For example:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "male|female")
@Column(name = "sex")
private String sex;
```

Now I have some JUnit test codebut its test all fields.

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Candidate>> violations = this.validator.validate(this.validCandidate, Candidate.class);
assertTrue(violations.isEmpty());
```

How can I test only sex for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validator.validateProperty(this.validCandidate, "sex", Default.class);
```

Comment: What purpose of last argument? With him I get Exception:
   javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes . But without everything is okay

Comment: This refers to the group type which is used to proceed to selective validations. As mentionned in the javadoc, not providing anything is the same as providing it explicitly.